# Java dependency will not import

Tags: java, intellij-idea

This is an extreme newbie question. So apologies in advance!
I am trying to use the simplexml library.
I have this at the top of my Main.java

import org.simpleframework.xml.Serializer;

and I have this in my pom.xml

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.simpleframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>simple-xml</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.4</version>
    </dependency>
```

Two days ago this worked fine... but today i open intellij and the 
import org.simpleframework.xml.Serializer; declaration is erroring, as it doesn't seem to be able to find the library and the rest of my program is now erroring all over the place.

I am a really newbie to all over this so please be gentle but any suggestions would be hugely appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

can you try deleting your local maven repo

C:\Documents and Settings\username.m2 in windows and run the app again.

Comment: so local repo got corrupted files, I face this quite often